# Get value from a dictionary key in django template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I need to get the value from an specific key of a dictionary passed to a django template. Something like:

```
...    
a = "string1"
b = "string2"
dic = {'a':a, 'b':b}
return render(request, 'index.html', {...,
'dic':dic})
```

In the template, shouldn't `{{ dic.a }}` return *string1*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
a = "string1"
b = "string2"
dic = {'a':a, 'b':b}
return render(request, 'index.html', dic)
```

Then you can get it directly using `{{a}}` in your template.

Comment: Didn't work. It seems the dictionary is not being passed to the template.

Comment: @LucasVeiga can you post your views, urls and template code ?

Comment: Nevermind, it was something else in the urls. Thank you for asking for it. By the way, {{a}} didn't work. {{dic.a}} works as it should thou.